# how to select * from multiple table with condition in Heidi sql

Tags: heidisql

I want to select all column from multiple table with a condition where, but I want to run the query to display all to review and delete some row.

I only use a query like this before
select * from users where section=15

now because of multiple tables with same column section, I want to run the query to display other 6 table with that condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

select * from table1 union all select * from table2  ...   union all select * from table6